# trimming portion of values in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want just the first 10 characters of each value in the array.

Here is the array:

```
array(['2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000']
```

I would like to write code that will give me this:

```
array(['2018-06-30','2018-06-30'   .... etc
```

Here's an update:
My code is:

```
x = np.array(df4['per_end_date'])
x
```

the output is:

```
array(['2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000', etc
```

I would like just the first 10 characters of each value in the array.
The following code give me the error IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

```
x = np.array([y[:9] for y in x])
```

Comment: There must be other elements in this `x` array, e.g empty string. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Although `numpy` isn't always the best way to manipulate strings, you can vectorize this operation, and as always, vectorized functions should be prefered to iteration.

***Setup***

```
arr = np.array(['2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000'],
  dtype='<U29')
```

---

Using **`np.frombuffer`**

```
np.frombuffer(
    arr.view((str, 1 )).reshape(arr.shape[0], -1)[:, :10].tostring(),
    dtype=(str,10)
)
```

```
array(['2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30',
       '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-09-30'],
      dtype='<U10')
```

***Timings***

```
arr = np.repeat(arr, 10000)

%timeit np.array([y[:10] for y in arr])
48.6 ms ± 961 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
np.frombuffer(
    arr.view((str, 1 )).reshape(arr.shape[0], -1)[:, :10].tostring(),
    dtype=(str,10)
)

6.87 ms ± 311 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.array(arr,dtype= 'datetime64[D]')
44.9 ms ± 2.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite basic task of working with lists in python

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array(['2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
           '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
           '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
           '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000'])
numpy.array([y[:10] for y in x])
# array(['2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30',
#        '2018-06-30', '2018-09-30'], 
#        dtype='|S10')
```

For more information you should read a bit of documentation on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: you dont have to write 0 in your slice though

Comment: I removed the "0" in "0:9", but got the same error.

Comment: Can you show the data for which you have the error? It works fine for the example you have provided

Comment: @user3672037 please don't edit my answers for your response but instead comment or edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

```
df4['per_end_date'].dtype
```

output:

```
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

So, the following code worked perfectly.

```
x = np.array(df4['per_end_date'],dtype= 'datetime64[D]')
x
```

output:

```
array(['2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30',
   '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-06-30', '2018-09-30',
   '2018-09-30', '2018-09-30', '2018-09-30', '2018-09-30',
   '2018-09-30', '2018-09-30', '2018-09-30', '2018-09-30', etc
```

Great when you can figure it out.  :)